# python module to password protect existing pdf files

Tags: python, pdf, password-protection

is there a python module to password protect existing pdf files?

Answer (score 4):

Try [pyPDF](http://pybrary.net/pyPdf/), the `PdfFileWriter` has a `encrypt` method.

Comment: @vivek I tried with adobe reader, evince and gv. All demanded a password.